# VueJS Bulma Sweet modal always toggles to the top of the page inside For loop

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, modal-dialog, bulma

I am using Vue JS and Bulma Frameworks. To show the modal I am using .
I have list of items(10)  which is displayed in a For Loop. In every item I have a button which opens the sweet modal. No matter which button I click, the modal is displayed at the top of the page always. Can anyone  help me how to show the modal near to the clicked button?

**Template index.html**

```
        <div class="content column is-full-mobile no-devices-found-wraper">
        <div class="columns is-mobile">
            <div class="column is-full-mobile ">
                <div class="columns is-mobile is-marginless">
                    <div class="column  is-half-mobile padding-bottom- 
                        zero padding-top-3">mobile devices:</div>
                    <div class="column padding-bottom-zero padding-top-3">
                        <a @click.stop.prevent="openDeviceModal()" 
                            class="add_icon is-pulled-right add-location-btn level- 
                            item">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>ADD ITEMS
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**sweet-modal outside for loop**

```
        <sweet-modal class="Add mobile device" ref="deviceAddLocation" 
        von:close="closeModal">
        <form @submit.prevent="saveDeviceToLocation">
            <div class="field add-devices-height-with-error">
                <label class="label" >mobile device Name</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </sweet-modal>
```

**//index.vue-- openDeviceModal()//**

```
    openDeviceModal() {
            this.isModalOpen = true;
            this.$refs.deviceAddLocation.blocking = true;
            this.$refs.deviceAddLocation.open();
        }
```

**//CSS//**

```
    .isModalOpen {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .sweet-modal {
        overflow: inherit;
    }

    .sweet-modal-overlay {
        background: transparent !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    .sweet-modal .sweet-content {
        padding-top: 10px;
        }

        .sweet-modal.is-visible {
        transform: translate(-62%, -50%) !important
        }


        sweet-modal .sweet-box-actions {
        top: 15px !important;
        }
```

Comment: Please share the codes you have tried so far.

Comment: when you ask a question stay connected and reply to comments to clarify it

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I will upload soon

Comment: Updated question with code

Comment: I tried changing the css properties. But still it shows the modal at the top of the page. Is there any best way to show modal in for loop using buttons?